# Arduino array input

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have this Arduino function for a smart door lock but the thing is the password its taking is completely wrong it's supposed to take 4 inputs as password.
Let's say I input it this way:

```
input: 1
output: Password: 1  1
input: 2
output: Password 1 2112
input: 3
output: Password is Long
```

This is what is displayed on the LCD screen.
This is the code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
String UID1 = "A3 14 95 1A";  // First UID
String UID2 = "BC 71 16 4A";  // Second UID
byte lock = 0;

Servo servo;
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8, 7, 6, 5};
byte colPins[COLS] = {4, 3, 2, A1};

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

char password[] = "1234";
char enteredPassword[5] = "";
int enteredPasswordIndex = 0;
bool enteringPassword = false;
unsigned long unlockedTime = 0;
const unsigned long lockDelay = 5000;

// Initialize the LCD screen with the I2C address
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(A2);
  servo.write(0);
  SPI.begin();
  rfid.PCD_Init();
  lcd.init();
  delay(5);
  lcd.backlight();
lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
lcd.print("Put your Card");
lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
lcd.print("or Password :)");
  delay(3000); // Wait for 5 seconds
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
  rfidControl();
  keypadControl();
}
void DoorReLock(){
  lcd.print("Door will lock itself in 5 seconds: ");
  for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Door will lock itself in ");
    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print(String(i) + " seconds");
    delay(1000);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Locking door...");
  servo.write(0);
}

void rfidControl() {
  if (!rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;
  if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;

  Serial.print("NUID tag is: ");
  String ID = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
    ID.concat(String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    ID.concat(String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  ID.toUpperCase();

  if ((ID.substring(1) == UID2 || ID.substring(1) == UID1) && lock == 0) {
    servo.write(90);
    Serial.println("Door is locked");
  
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Door is open");
    delay(1500);
    lock = 1;
    DoorReLock();
  } else if ((ID.substring(1) == UID2 || ID.substring(1) == UID1) && lock == 1) {
    servo.write(0);
    Serial.println("Door is open");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    DoorReLock();
    lock = 0;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wrong card!");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Wrong card!");
    delay(1500);
  }

}

 void keypadControl() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key != '\0') {
    Serial.print("Key pressed: ");
    Serial.println(key);

    // Append pressed key to entered password
    if (enteredPasswordIndex < sizeof(enteredPassword) - 1) {
      enteredPassword[enteredPasswordIndex] = key;
      enteredPasswordIndex++;
    }

    // Print entered password on LCD screen
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Password: ");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    lcd.print(enteredPassword);

    // Check if DCB key combination is entered
    if (key == 'D' && enteredPasswordIndex == 3 && enteredPassword[0] == 'D' && enteredPassword[1] == 'C' && enteredPassword[2] == 'B') {
      // Ask for old password
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
      lcd.print("Enter old password");

      char oldPassword[sizeof(password)] = "";
      int oldPasswordIndex = 0;
      bool enteringOldPassword = true;

      while (enteringOldPassword) {
        char oldKey = keypad.getKey();
        if (oldKey != '\0' && oldKey != '#' && oldKey != '*' && oldKey != 'A' && oldKey != 'B' && oldKey != 'C' && oldKey != 'D') {
          oldPassword[oldPasswordIndex] = oldKey;
          oldPasswordIndex++;
          lcd.setCursor(oldPasswordIndex - 1, 1);
          lcd.print('*');
        }
        if (oldPasswordIndex == sizeof(password) - 1) {
          enteringOldPassword = false;
        }
      }

      if (strcmp(oldPassword, password) == 0) {
        // Ask for new password
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Enter new password");

        char newPassword[sizeof(password)] = "";
        int newPasswordIndex = 0;
        bool enteringNewPassword = true;

        while (enteringNewPassword) {
          char newKey = keypad.getKey();
          if (newKey != '\0' && newKey != '#' && newKey != '*' && newKey != 'A' && newKey != 'B' && newKey != 'C' && newKey != 'D') {
            newPassword[newPasswordIndex] = newKey;
            newPasswordIndex++;
            lcd.setCursor(newPasswordIndex - 1, 1);
            lcd.print('*');
          }
          if (newPasswordIndex == sizeof(password) - 1) {
            enteringNewPassword = false;
          }
        }

        // Update password and notify user
        strncpy(password, newPassword, sizeof(password));
        password[sizeof(password) - 1] = '\0';
         lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Password changed!");
        delay(1500);
        lcd.clear();
      } else {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Wrong password");
        delay(1500);
        lcd.clear();
      }

      // Reset entered password
      enteringPassword = false;
      memset(enteredPassword, 0, sizeof(enteredPassword)); 
        enteredPasswordIndex = 0;
} else if (key == '#') {
  Serial.println("Password is reset");
  memset(enteredPassword, 0, sizeof(enteredPassword));
  enteredPasswordIndex = 0;
  enteringPassword = false;
  unlockedTime = 0;
  lcd.print("Password is reset");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  delay(500); // Wait for 0.5 seconds
  lcd.clear();
} else if (key == 'A') {
  Serial.println("Door is Locked");
  servo.write(0);
  memset(enteredPassword, 0, sizeof(enteredPassword));
  enteredPasswordIndex = 0;
  enteringPassword = false;
  unlockedTime = 0;
  lcd.print("Door is Locked");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  delay(500); // Wait for 0.5 seconds
  lcd.clear();
} else if (key == '*') {
  Serial.println("Submit");
  if (strcmp(enteredPassword, password) == 0) {
    servo.write(90);
    Serial.println("Door unlocked");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Door unlocked");
    unlockedTime = millis();
    DoorReLock();
  } else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Wrong password");
    delay(1000); // Wait for 1 second
    lcd.clear();
  }
  enteringPassword = false;
  memset(enteredPassword, 0, sizeof(enteredPassword));
  enteredPasswordIndex = 0;
  delay(1500); // Wait for 1.5 seconds
} else if (enteringPassword) {
  if (enteredPasswordIndex >= sizeof(enteredPassword) - 1) {
    Serial.println("Password too long");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Password is long");
    delay(1500); // Wait for 1.5 seconds
    lcd.clear();
    memset(enteredPassword, 0, sizeof(enteredPassword));

  } else {
    enteredPassword[enteredPasswordIndex] = key;
    enteredPasswordIndex++;
    Serial.print("Entered password: ");
    Serial.println(enteredPassword);
    lcd.setCursor(enteredPasswordIndex - 1, 1);
    lcd.print(key);
  }
} else {
  Serial.println("Enter password");
  enteringPassword = true;
  enteredPassword[0] = key;
  enteredPasswordIndex = 1;
  // lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
 // lcd.print("Password: ");
}

// If the door is unlocked and the lock delay has passed
if (unlockedTime != 0 && millis() - unlockedTime >= lockDelay) {
  servo.write(0);
  Serial.println("Door locked");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("Door locked");
  unlockedTime = 0; 
}
  }
 }
```

I though the password change is the problem since adding it the problem happened but I removed it completely and its still the same so I probably did something wrong while trying to print it on the LCD but I cant seem to find it.